# What is the most basic Asio execution context for manually driving non-blocking native handles?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, asio

Let's say I have an existing program with an existing main loop done "the traditional way", and I can register to be notified when a file descriptor is readable, etc.  For the purposes of this question, let's presume that we don't want to rework this loop to use Asio.

It seems that I can then take, for example, an Asio datagram socket, set it to `native_non_blocking()`, monitor its fd for read events, and then react to such events by performing "blocking" `receive_from()` calls and expect them to return the equivalent of `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` via an `error_code`.  Similarly for write.

(Let's ignore whether this is "in the spirit" of Asio.  That's not really the purpose of the question.)

My question then is, what is the minimum execution context that I would need to provide to do this?  It seems like I wouldn't really need an `io_context` (which, on Linux, for example, opens a few additional fds for epoll, signalfd, and timerfd) because I should never actually *use* it.  It also seems like I wouldn't really want a `system_context` or a `thread_pool` because I don't really want anything to run on some other threads.

Is there some pre-defined "same thread" context that would be appropriate here?  If now, how would one go about constructing such a thing?  Or, does the exposed API on an Asio socket still "sometimes" actually use the functionality of an `io_context` under the covers even when the making "blocking" `receive_from()` or `send_to()` calls on a non-blocking socket in some hidden micro event loop (and if so, why)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there some pre-defined "same thread" context that would be appropriate here?

`io_context` does only provide the context, not subsuming anything about what threads use it. Therefore

```
boost::asio::io_context io;
io.run();
```

Is already your minimal context.

Your confusion then seems to come from the fact that `run()` intends to provide the event-loop, which appears as blocking behaviour. There are two ways about this:

- do not call `run()` anywhere (this limits your options, but if indeed you ONLY vow to use the native backdoors (`native_handle()` and friends) you shouldn't care.
- integrate `run_one()` or `poll_one()` into your event loop and be happy. This allows you to use the full extent of Asio services that build on the io_context abstraction and its executor(s), while you can obviously also use the backdoors¹.

Side note: do not forget to properly handle exceptions emanating from `{run,poll}[_one]()`

---

¹ at your own risk, because combining them means you understand the implications on all the platforms you are going to support

Comment: I actually am not confused by `run()` (but thanks). I guess I am asking if I can implement an `io_context` replacement that doesn't open any resources (not even an epoll fd, etc.). And, if I use only the backdoors, are there any promises about what functions get called on the context or executor?

Comment: I guess my answer is right in the documentation after all: "Synchronous operations on I/O objects implicitly run the io_context object for an individual operation." So, in other words, like you said, an `io_context` is as minimal as it gets. Thanks.